# clang_complete: No python support available

Tags: plugin-coc, spacevim, plugin-clang-complete

I have installed SpaceVim. My `init.toml` file looks as follows:

```
#=============================================================================
# dark_powered.toml --- dark powered configuration example for SpaceVim
# Copyright (c) 2016-2017 Wang Shidong & Contributors
# Author: Wang Shidong < wsdjeg at 163.com >
# URL: https://spacevim.org
# License: GPLv3
#=============================================================================

# All SpaceVim option below [option] section
[options]
    # set spacevim theme. by default colorscheme layer is not loaded,
    # if you want to use more colorscheme, please load the colorscheme
    # layer
    colorscheme = "gruvbox"
    colorscheme_bg = "dark"
    # Disable guicolors in basic mode, many terminal do not support 24bit
    # true colors
    enable_guicolors = true
    # Disable statusline separator, if you want to use other value, please
    # install nerd fonts
    statusline_separator = "arrow"
    statusline_inactive_separator = "arrow"
    buffer_index_type = 4
    enable_tabline_filetype_icon = true
    enable_statusline_mode = false

# Enable autocomplete layer
[[layers]]
name = 'autocomplete'
auto_completion_return_key_behavior = "complete"
auto_completion_tab_key_behavior = "smart"

[[layers]]
name = 'shell'
default_position = 'top'
default_height = 30

[[layers]]
  name = "lang#c"

[options]
  colorscheme = "desert"
  colorscheme_bg = "dark"

[options]
    autocomplete_method = "coc"
```

Now, when I open a blank c++ file, I get the following:

[image: Issue]

I can't seem to figure this out as I just installed VIM. Could someone kindly explain how to fix this?

## EDIT

I am using Mac OS, I installed neovim using `brew install neovim`. This works fine.

I then installed spacevim:
`curl -sLf https://spacevim.org/install.sh | bash`

The instructions for this install command are here: [Link](https://spacevim.org/quick-start-guide/#linux-and-macos)

Running the `:version` command inside nvim gives this:

```
:version                                                                                                                                              
NVIM v0.4.4
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.0.5
Compilation: /usr/bin/clang -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DNDEBUG -DMIN_LOG_LEVEL=3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-unused-parameter -Wstrict-prototypes
 -std=gnu99 -Wshadow -Wconversion -Wmissing-prototypes -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wvla -fstack-protector-strong -fno-common -fdiagnostics-color=auto -DINCLUDE_GE
NERATED_DECLARATIONS -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNVIM_MSGPACK_HAS_FLOAT32 -DNVIM_UNIBI_HAS_VAR_FROM -I/tmp/neovim-20200808-89283-1us0ytm/neovim-0.4.4/build/config -I/tmp/
neovim-20200808-89283-1us0ytm/neovim-0.4.4/src -I/usr/local/include -I/tmp/neovim-20200808-89283-1us0ytm/neovim-0.4.4/deps-build/include -I/Library/Developer/
CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/tmp/neovim-20200808-89283-1us0ytm/neovim-0.4.4/build/src/nvim/auto -I/tm
p/neovim-20200808-89283-1us0ytm/neovim-0.4.4/build/include
Compiled by brew@Catalina

Features: +acl +iconv +tui
See ":help feature-compile"

   system vimrc file: "$VIM/sysinit.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.4.4/share/nvim"

Run :checkhealth for more info
```

## EDIT2

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Take a look at `vim --version` or equivalently output of `:version` from inside Vim. Please [edit] the question to include that information in your question. Looks like you're on Mac OS. How did you install Vim there? That's probably relevant here...

Comment: Thanks @filbranden, I have edited the original que. I installed neovim, then I installed spacevim. I had vim already on my mac by default I think.

Comment: Try `:checkhealth`? See also https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ#python-support-isnt-working

Comment: Thanks, from the looks of it looks like I will need to install neovim for pip3

Comment: If you figure it out, please post an answer with what fixed it for you!